# What would actually be the ecological impact of deep sea mining?

Tags: ecology, environment

In the last few months I have read a number of articles with increasing alarm concerning the potential of many countries soon engaging in deep sea mining. The idea is that in order to produce numerous technologies key to moving green, such as batteries, industry needs a good supply of metals that are currently rather rare, such as manganese or cobalt, and there are so-called *polymetallic nodules* covering various parts of the sea floor (for example the Clarion-Clipperton Zone) believed to be rich in these materials.

As covered in numerous places, for example [here](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2023/jul/08/future-of-deep-sea-mining-hangs-in-balance-as-opposition-grows), the International Seabed Authority was supposed to draft some kind of agreement on what kind of mining like this is acceptable but the deadline has passed for it to set down laws so currently we're in a kind of "wild west" scenario where many companies can mine down there potentially with little regulation.

My question is: **what will be the ecological impact of this kind of mining?**

In some sense, there are obvious arguments as to why we shouldn't do something like this. One would be that it is a relatively untouched part of the world (in terms of human influence) and that fact *inherently* gives the idea of leaving it alone value to me. However, this could be applied to absolutely anywhere and we do probably have to occasionally conduct mining, farming etc. activities somewhere so what makes this different?

**Let's imagine two counterfactuals:**

One is that instead of deep sea mining, the recent events had concerned mining in the Amazon rainforest or the Great Barrier Reef. I have chosen these places as being ones I know are widely accepted to be extremely biodiverse and home to numerous unique species. Clearly this would be horrific for life on earth and I would hope most people on this site would be against it unless there really was no other option.

Another is that instead of deep sea mining, recent events had concerned mining in the middle of some deserts, say the Gobi. In this case, there is wildlife in the desert which is of intrinsic interest (for example, they give plentiful examples of extremophiles) but broadly speaking there's barely anything there. Arguably it would be difficult to find a better place to conduct mining if you want to minimise ecological impact! Thus I can't imagine many biologists being as concerned beyond the fact that these are again relatively untouched and thus hold intrinsic value.

I am interested in where the deep sea mining lies between these two extremes. My (admittedly fairly lay person) perspective is that on the sea bed it was definitely a surprise by biologists to find complex life but that, broadly speaking, there still isn't much going on. Furthermore, the Clarion-Clipperton Zone (the major area of interest) varies in depth between 4-5.5km deep. If we say it's on average 4.75km deep that's around 11 Empire State Buildings end-to-end stacked on top of each other! The point is that at such a depth, can life down there or activities down there really affect or be affected by things happening above, say at the surface?

As I understand, there is such a separation between life down there and above that creatures share very few similarities at the bottom to surface dwellers (if you need a specific example of how this distance can affect lifeforms, consider [deep sea gigantism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep-sea_gigantism) and we're looking even deeper!). Surely then even major activities down there will have little effect on the rest of the biosphere?

---

I just want to give a postscript to this question that I do not support mining in untouched areas of the world. This question is not supposed to advocate for deep sea mining but purely to understand better what is currently going on by asking experts.

Comment: In 10, or 5, years time we will be able to look back on the evidence.